# How to check the color of shape?

Tags: java, swing

I am making a game of life project. I have a 2d array of rectangles and I also have a 2d array of 1's and 0's. These separate 2d arrays act as the FRONT END AND BACK END models

- I need a solution for the statement inside the loop
- I want to change the backed based on the COLOR of one of the squares in the front-end. My code `x.equals(java.awt.Color.red))` does not work. What is the correct solution?

```java
for (int i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0 ; j < squares[i].length ; j++) {

        **if (squares[i][j].equals(java.awt.Color.red))** {
            game.board2[i][j] = 1;

        }
        else //IF WHITE {
        game.board2[i][j] = 0;

    }
    game.update();
    this.gUpdate();
}
```

I checked with print statements and it just doesn't work.

Comment: `my code x.equals(java.awt.Color.red)) doesn't work`: probably because `squares[][]` doesn't have the type `Color[][]`. And a good naming for color of squares would be:  `squareColor[][]`

Comment: thanks sage. How might I go about finding the color of my rectangle 2d's

Comment: Try to `System.out.println` the actual color in `squares[i][j]`. If it's red, it should say `java.awt.Color[r=255,g=0,b=0]`.

Comment: declare your `squares` as a 2d array of `Color`: for exampple `Color[][] squares = new Color[4][5];`

Comment: how do I print the color?

Comment: Assuming `squares` is a `Color[][]`, it's just `System.out.println(squares[i][j])`.

Comment: can't. they are declared as a 2d array of the object "square". No way to check the color of my rectangle2D component with a simple statement?

Comment: I like your way. would it be possible to make both work together. Thanks again for helping me! g2g for now

Comment: Why do you have two questions on this topic (http://stackoverflow.com/q/20587558/131872)? How are people going to keep track of all the suggestions that have been made in both postings?

Comment: @camickr  I *thought* this looked familiar.  OP - you've just earn your first 2 down votes and close votes.  The close votes were because a) this is a duplicate of the other b) the other should supply an SSCCE.  The down votes were for ignoring my initial advice and wasting our time with a 2nd question.

Comment: I appologize for my lazy post. I had to go to work and wanted something when I came home to work on at 10pm. thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the objects in `squares` seem to be `Rectangle2D`s, you can do two things:

1. Create another array `Color[][] colors` to keep track of the colors of your squares. `colors[i][j]` should be the color of the square in `squares[i][j]`.
2. Subclass `Rectangle2D` and add a `Color` field.

If you don't actually use the squares in `squares`, but only check the color, do as @Sage suggested and make `squares` a `Color[][]`.

Comment: Thank you so much mdriesen for the comment. I am still rather bad programmer and sometimes I forget even the basics. Wonderfully helpful you are.

Comment: Hi. I fixed my program and I think it is quite nice now. I used an array of Color to keep track of the color. The problem is, I cant quite seem to test which color it contains. Do I have to make my own getColor() method or is there something built in for me. Thanks so much, again

Comment: Post the rest of your code like @andrew suggested in the comments on your question. It's a bit difficult to help you further otherwise.